# Finding Common Items in arrays

Tags: javascript, performance, complexity, typescript

My goal is to get a list of related **statementIds** in order of most repeated.

In my database I have stems(Words):

```
+---------+-----------------+
|  Stem   |   StatementId   |
+---------+-----------------+
| Hello   | [2,46,62]       |
| Good    | [1,123,45]      |
| Morning | [23,2436,12312] |
+---------+-----------------+
```

My steps:

1. Get all **statementIds**

   `[6, 86],[6],[4],[3, 86],[...]`
2. Create an empty object, and everytime i see a number,increase its value (or set to 1 if it hasen't been seen before)

    `{2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 1, 6: 11, 85: 1, 86: 5, 87: 1, 89: 1}`
3. Sort the object by the attribute and put it in an array of relevancy.

    `["6", "86", "3", "89", "87", "85", "4", "2"]`

Full code:

```js
getAllStatementIdFromStem = async (stems: string[]) => {
    const ids: { [key: number]: number } = {};
    await this.getBulkStem(stems).toArray((stems: Stem[]) =>
      stems.map(({ statements }) =>
        statements.forEach((statementId: number) => {
          typeof ids[statementId] === "undefined"
            ? (ids[statementId] = 1)
            : ids[statementId]++;
        })
      )
    );
    return Object.entries(ids)
      .sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1])
      .reverse()
      .map(x => x[0]);
  };
```

Could I be doing something more effectively? I feel like I am doing way too many extra steps.

Comment: Couple of questions: are statement IDs and sentence IDs the same? Can you provide an end to end example, e.g. for X input you should get Y output. Means that I can step through the code on my end, using your input, and see if any steps can be optimised.

Comment: Updated the names.
input = [ [1], [65, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89], [2], [1, 2]]
output = [1, 2, 89, 88, 87, 86, 85, 65]

Answer (score 2):

Overall looks good. I think following improvements can be suggested.

1.Instead of this

```
typeof ids[statementId] === "undefined"
  ? (ids[statementId] = 1)
  : ids[statementId]++;
```

How about this for more readability

```
ids[statementId] = (ids[statementId] || 0) + 1;
```

2.Instead of doing `sort` and immediately `reverse`. You can change sort function (with descending order) so that you can avoid `reverse` call.